# What distribution is $\frac{x}{\theta}\exp(-x^2/(2 \theta))$?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

What distribution is  $\dfrac{x}{\theta}\exp(-x^2/(2\theta))$ like? I cannot find a similar distribution.

Comment: If $X^2$ has an exponential distribution with mean $2\theta$ then this is the pdf of $X$ ( assuming $x>0$).

Answer (score 1):

This is called a [Rayleigh distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_distribution) (Wikipedia).

Comment: With the usual parameterization $\theta=\sigma^2$.